# how to do port forwarding if my router wan ip is different from public ip?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, ip-camera

I have an IP camera and i want to access it from anywhere around the world. I have configured my NETGEAR-router JNR1010 for port forwarding but the WAN IP it gives me is different from the public ip when viewed from the local pc on the same network.

I tried accessing IP camera with the public ip, but the webpage does not take me anywhere.It can be accessed through the WAN ip which the router gave me but from the pc which is on the same network as IP-camera not from the outside network.

I have an ACT FIBERNET internet connection and i think they havenot provided me the static ip, instead they provided me some local ip using NAT.

When i do trace route using command tracert in windows:
I get this in return (too many hops comes in between, till it gets to some static ip) the image link is attached:

[tracert image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpBDn.png)

If i opt for static ip, internet provider will charge more, IS there any way by which i can access my IP camera through internet without having to change my internet plan?

Can i configure my IP camera to send stream to some external server and by logging on to that, i can access the IP camera stream ?

Answer (score 6):

You're behind carrier grade NAT so port forwards won't work.

Your options are:

- Subscribe to a VPN provider that assigns dedicated IPs per user and allows port forwarding. Also requires a router that can connect to a VPN (many ISP models will not be able to do this) as the camera itself cannot run a VPN client.
- Pay for a static IP address

Either way you're paying more, but the latter will give better performance in most cases and is simpler to setup. You can evaluate pricing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following solution (depending on type of modem):

- Register a dyndns account (f.e.: http://dyn.com/dns/). This will make sure you can always connect to your private network on a name base (even though your IP-address is changing).
- Set your modem in bridge mode (forward all traffic to your router).
- Your router now handles your internal traffic and you can setup your port forwardings on that machine.

This is a solution if you're want to stay on a dynamic public address. Static addresses will cost you more a month (where I'm from, it's almost 1/3 of total internet cost). If money is no issue, ask for a static IP-address, makes it much more easier.

Answer (score -1):

Either talk to your ISP and get password of router and the 
do port forwarding at both lan and Wan routers.

Or You can use reverse ssh and push data to client PC on outside network